# How to define application specific classpath in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath

let's suppose we have two web applications under "webapps" folder; "abc" and "xyz". Is there a way to define a different classpath folder per application? In Tomcat something like "abc.classpath=Directory_A; xyz.classpath=Directory_B" would be greate.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: So you want classpath only to be Directory_A and nothing else right?

Answer (score 3):

Your applications will all load the TOMCAT_HOME/lib contents. Other than that each of your webapps will load whatever's in their own WEB-INF/lib & WEB-INF/classes folders.

Comment: yes, you are right Steve but i don't want my war files contain all third party jars so i don't want to put them into WEB-INF/lib directory. Is there an another solution?

Comment: You need your 3d party jars to make the thing run. If you wanted to share them between webapps you could put them in the tomcat/lib but that's likely to be more trouble than it's worth - if the versions don't stay in sync it would cause problems. You're not going to save memory by putting them elsewhere, as the jvm will have to load them anyway if you need them. And you're not going to make it more transferable - you'll want to transfer the war intact with the 3d party jars anyway so it runs the same in any deployment env.  Just put them in the war like everyone else and dont worry about it.

Comment: so i don't want my 3d jars into tomcat/lib directory. if tomcat loaded jars per application from a different directory, our war file's size could be smaller and we could transer war file over internet easier.

Comment: For the sake of a few megabytes (or a few tens of megabytes) you make your application non-portable and introduce a source of bugs. to save a few seconds on your deployment you must now make sure that all of your deployment boxes have the same jars loaded. If you want to update a jar version you must update all the deployment environments in sync. You also must make sure that all of your webapps use the same versions. You could always structure your work as a maven or an ivy project and just run the builds locally - those will build local wars with the correct contents.

Comment: Hi Steve, you don't understand my problem. I know disadvantages of using same classpath for all webapps. Just because of this i opened this thread. If you know, please tell the way to give classpaths per application under webapps(except WEB-INF/lib directory). Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

i found a way...

my expoloded web application' s name is "abc". I created "$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/abc.xml" file and defined

```
<Context className="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext">
     <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
             virtualClasspath="/externalClasspath/*.jar"/>
</Context>
```

Are there any ideas about this problem? Because it didn't work.